Where does output from QGIS Processing "SpatiaLite execute SQL (registered DB)" go?
I can run SQLite queries on a SQLite database in the Processing module named "SpatiaLite execute SQL (registered DB)".
This SQL runs with no error messages:

CREATE table Tur_og_Deltur_2016 AS  SELECT
t2.SessionId,
t1.TurId,
t2.PrimMode,
t2.OrigMuncode,
t2.DestMuncode,
t2.OrigGMMzone,
t2.DestGMMzone,
t1.Delturnr,
t1.ModeDwelTime,
t1.StageMode,
t1.ModeGroup,
t1.StageDrivPass,
t1.StageLength,
t1.StageWaitMin,
t1.StageStartMsm,
t1.StageDurationMin,
t1.Route,
t1.FromStation,
t1.ToStation,
t1.FuelType,
t1.GramCO2,
t1.GramCO2eq,
t1.FuelConsumpMJ FROM
DELTUR t1
INNER JOIN TUR t2 ON t1.TurId = t2.TurId;

But where do I find the created table? It is not added to my database and it is not loaded in my QGIS canvas.
Note: There is no geography - it is only a SQLite data table I am working on.

Have you confirmed your SQL Query works outside of QGIS? I just ran a simple CREATE TABLE TEST as select * from EXISTING_TABLE; and the table was created in the database.

I can run the SQL Query in "DB Browser for SQLite". I can make some simple queries work in QGIS too but to me it looks like the problem is that "SpatiaLite execute SQL (registered DB)" only can handle one SQL statement at a time? If I paste several statements in the SQL window only the first one will be executed (but still no warnings or error messages from QGIS)

I wouldn't expect more than one statement to work, but that sounds like a different question to what you posted which is a sing;e statement not working.

Right you are - I got wiser in the process ;-)
